# HTML and Javascript: Multiple images sharing a single map

Tags: javascript, html, imagemap

I want to reuse an image map for several different images.
I'd like Javascript that will be able to know that I clicked on Area 2 of image3 for example.
Is this possible using Javascript?
If so how do I pass the image id to the Javascript?
Thanks!

```
<map name="bg_over" id="bg_over">
<area shape="poly" coords="2,44,44,2,44,44" href="team2.html" alt="" />
<area shape="poly" coords="0,0,0,43,44,0" href="team1.html" alt="" />
</map>

<a href="#"><img src="/Training/rumble_ora/images/bg.gif" width="44" height="44" id="image1" name="image1" usemap="#bg_over"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="/Training/rumble_ora/images/bg.gif" width="44" height="44" id="image2" name="image2" usemap="#bg_over"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="/Training/rumble_ora/images/bg.gif" width="44" height="44" id="image3" name="image3" usemap="#bg_over"></a>
```

Comment: have you tried onclick in area tag? i think its possible

Comment: Yes... I know I can do an onClick. The issue I'm facing is how to tell the onClick that I did the click on image3 and not image2 or image1. How do I pass to the onClick WHICH image I clicked?

Comment: i dont know if your best option is to do the onclick in the image and check the coordinates with javascript to ensure that the user clicked in the area you want , or to crate a bg_over for each image and then do the onclick inside de area, maybe someone has a better idea how to handle that

Comment: You have three images, but in the code you posted above, they're identical. In that case, why do you need to know which one you clicked? You either need to tell us why you have one areamap for three images, combine the images into one, or to create multiple areamaps.